# duda eliminar duplicados diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios

tengo una duda, debo realizar un ejercicio en el cuál además de eliminar duplicados de un diccionario con listas, debo eliminar cualquier mini lista en el diccionario que no contenga el caracter "@", y un caracter ".", pensé en pasar el diccionario pasado como parámetro a lista mediante el método items, y después crear una lista vacia y si el diccionario no está en la lista vacia le hago un append, pero me falta el tema de los otros caracteres.

Mi código es este:

```
def enviomasivo(dicc1):
    listavacia=[]
    valores=list(dicc1.items())
    diccionariofinal=dict(listavacia)

    for elem in valores:
        if elem not in listavacia:
            listavacia.append(elem)
    return dict(listavacia)

print(enviomasivo({"Martín Rodríguez":["arodri@ucu.edu.uy"],"Martín Rodríguez":["arodri@ucu.edu.uy"],"Joséperez":["arodriucu.edu.uy"]}))
```

Comment: ¿Sabes que un diccionario no puede tener keys repetidas? No da error, pero si tienes: `{'color':'azul', 'color':'rojo'}` se reduce automáticamente a: `{'color':'rojo'}`, así que el diccionario que estas definiendo ya está perdiendo una de sus `key:value`.

Comment: No veo que estés usando el método `.items()` en ningún momento. Por otro lado, el modo más _pythónico_ para hacer algo así es usando [compresión de diccionarios](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-comprehension), pero igual no puedes emplearlo todavía para este ejercicio.